# Including citations/references in docstring for doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

Is there standard way to include a references section for a doxygen docstring in C++? For example, for documenting references that influenced the implementation, the python library `statsmodels` sometimes includes a `References` section in the docstring (see [multivariate PCA](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/_modules/statsmodels/multivariate/pca.html#PCA)).

To illustrate what I currently have, the below code

```cpp
/**
 * @brief Return laplacian as linear operator on u(x,y) assuming homogenous dirichlet BCs.
 * 
 * From [MIT Intro Linear PDEs](https://github.com/mitmath/18303/blob/master/supp_material/poissonFD.ipynb)
 * 
 * @param n Number of grid points in the x or y direction.
 * @return Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> 
 */
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> laplacian(size_t n);
```

generates the below in doxygen after calling `cmake --build build --targets docs` where `docs/` contains the corresponding `CMakeLists.txt` specifying which directory to get files to be documented,

[image]

but what I want is to move "From MIT Intro Linear PDEs" to something like

```cpp
/**
 * @brief Return laplacian as linear operator on u(x,y) assuming homogenous dirichlet BCs.
 * 
 * @param n Number of grid points in the x or y direction.
 * @return Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> 
 * @references
 * [1] : [MIT Intro Linear PDEs](https://github.com/mitmath/18303/blob/master/supp_material/poissonFD.ipynb)
 * [2] : some other reference here
 */
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> laplacian(size_t n);
```

in order to clearly delineate a references section like below,

[image]

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Did you have a a look at the `\cite` command?

Comment: I am using doxygen 1.9.1. I will look into the `\cite` command since presumably I will have to put the corresponding `.bib` file into some appropriate directory (probably `docs/` ?) and then update my `docs/CMakeLists.txt` as well. (I'm very new to both doxygen and cmake, so my assumptions could very well be wrong)

Comment: Assumptions don't look bad. Note that doxygen version 1.9.1 is from January 8, 2021, the current doxygen version is 1.10.0